# Godot 4 inventory error, I don't know where the error is coming from

Tags: godot

Godot 4.1.1.stable

images project:

[image: enter imageenter image description here description here][image]

code:

- inventory.gd:

```
`
extends Node2D

const SlotClass = preload("res://Inventory/Slot.gd")
@onready var inventory_slots = get_node("/root/Inventory/TextureRect/GridContainer")
var holding_item = null

func _ready():
    for inv_slot in inventory_slots.get_children():
        inv_slot.gui_input.connect(slot_gui_input.bind(inv_slot))
        
func slot_gui_input(event: InputEvent, slot: SlotClass):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && event.pressed:
            if holding_item != null:
                if !slot.item: # Place holding item to slot
                    slot.PutIntoSlot(holding_item)
                    holding_item = null
            else: # Swap holding item with item in slot
                var temp_item = slot.item
                slot.PickFromSlot()
                temp_item.global_position = event.global_position
                slot.PutIntoSlot(holding_item)
                holding_item = temp_item
        elif slot.item:
            holding_item = slot.item
            slot.PickFromSlot()
            holding_item.global_position = get_global_mouse_position()
func _input(envent):
    if holding_item:
        holding_item.global_position = get_global_mouse_position()
`
```

- Item.gd

```
`
extends Node2D

var picked = false

func _ready():
    if randi() % 2 == 0:
        $TextureRect.texture = load("res://Inventory/Item/Iron Sword.png")
    else:
        $TextureRect.texture = load("res://Inventory/Item/Tree Branch.png")
`
```

- Slot.gd

```
`extends Panel

var default_tex = preload("res://Inventory/item_slot_default_background.png")
var empty_tex = preload("res://Inventory/item_slot_empty_background.png")

var default_style: StyleBoxTexture = null
var empty_style: StyleBoxTexture = null

var ItemClass = preload("res://Inventory/Item/item.tscn")
var item = null

func _ready():
    default_style = StyleBoxTexture.new()
    empty_style = StyleBoxTexture.new()
    default_style.texture = default_tex
    empty_style.texture = empty_tex
    
    if randi() % 2 == 0:
        item = ItemClass.instantiate()
        add_child(item)
    refresh_style()
        
func refresh_style():
    if item == null:
        set("theme_override_styles/panel", empty_style)
    else:
        set("theme_override_styles/panel", default_style)

func PickFromSlot():
    remove_child(item)
    var inventoryNode = get_node_or_null("/root/Inventory")
    inventoryNode.add_child(item)
    item = null
    refresh_style()

func PutIntoSlot(new_item):
    item = new_item
    if item is Node2D:
        item.set_position(Vector2(0,0))
    var inventoryNode = find_parent("Inventory")
    inventoryNode.remove_child(item)
    add_child(item)
    refresh_style()`
```

I was following a tutorial for an inventory, the tutorial used Godot 3. whilst I use Godot 4. I don't know where the error is coming from, here's all my code, because I'm not good at English so I don't know how to express the error.
Pack:

- Iron Sword.png : [image]
- Tree Branch.png : [image]
- default_inventory_background.png : [image]
- item_slot_default_background.png : [image]
- item_slot_empty_background.png : [image]